# Can a version update (from 12.04 to 12.10) give driver problems?

Tags: drivers, updates

I recently installed 12.04.

Even though I'm not completely new to the Linux World, I wanted to ask this: I had a problem in video drivers, and I fixed it by a complete re-installation of the whole operating system. If I install the new version using the Update Manager (so without a complete re-installation), *will my drivers be the same as they are*? And *what about my data*?

Answer (score 1):

I've been updating Ubuntu from 10.10 since 12.04. My experience with drivers is mixed. Some upgrades solved problems (example: touchpad clicks started working properly after upgrading to 11.04), other upgrades caused problems I had fixed (especially with wifi) to start causing problems again.

I would try a liveUSB before upgrading. Also most problems are solved during the first month or two of a final release. 12.10 is not yet final; it's likely there are still bugs. If you want to reduce chances of having upgrading problems, wait until the end of the year or end of January before upgrading.